# Python 3 - Encode/Decode vs Bytes/Str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python3, coming from python2, and I am a bit confused with unicode fundamentals.
I've read some good posts, that made it all much clearer, however I see there are 2 methods on python 3, that handle encoding and decoding, and I'm not sure which one to use.

So the idea in python 3 is, that every string is unicode, and can be encoded and stored in bytes, or decoded back into unicode string again.

But there are 2 ways to do it:
`u'something'.encode('utf-8')` will generate `b'something'`, but so does `bytes(u'something', 'utf-8')`.
And `b'bytes'.decode('utf-8')` seems to do the same thing as `str(b'bytes', 'utf-8')`.

Now my question is, why are there 2 methods that seem to do the same thing, and is either better than the other (and why?) I've been trying to find answer to this on google, but no luck.

```
>>> original = '27岁少妇生孩子后变老'
>>> type(original)
<class 'str'>
>>> encoded = original.encode('utf-8')
>>> print(encoded)
b'27\xe5\xb2\x81\xe5\xb0\x91\xe5\xa6\x87\xe7\x94\x9f\xe5\xad\xa9\xe5\xad\x90\xe5\x90\x8e\xe5\x8f\x98\xe8\x80\x81'
>>> type(encoded)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> encoded2 = bytes(original, 'utf-8')
>>> print(encoded2)
b'27\xe5\xb2\x81\xe5\xb0\x91\xe5\xa6\x87\xe7\x94\x9f\xe5\xad\xa9\xe5\xad\x90\xe5\x90\x8e\xe5\x8f\x98\xe8\x80\x81'
>>> type(encoded2)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(encoded+encoded2)
b'27\xe5\xb2\x81\xe5\xb0\x91\xe5\xa6\x87\xe7\x94\x9f\xe5\xad\xa9\xe5\xad\x90\xe5\x90\x8e\xe5\x8f\x98\xe8\x80\x8127\xe5\xb2\x81\xe5\xb0\x91\xe5\xa6\x87\xe7\x94\x9f\xe5\xad\xa9\xe5\xad\x90\xe5\x90\x8e\xe5\x8f\x98\xe8\x80\x81'
>>> decoded = encoded.decode('utf-8')
>>> print(decoded)
27岁少妇生孩子后变老
>>> decoded2 = str(encoded2, 'utf-8')
>>> print(decoded2)
27岁少妇生孩子后变老
>>> type(decoded)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(decoded2)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(str(b'27\xe5\xb2\x81\xe5\xb0\x91\xe5\xa6\x87\xe7\x94\x9f\xe5\xad\xa9\xe5\xad\x90\xe5\x90\x8e\xe5\x8f\x98\xe8\x80\x81', 'utf-8'))
27岁少妇生孩子后变老
>>> print(b'27\xe5\xb2\x81\xe5\xb0\x91\xe5\xa6\x87\xe7\x94\x9f\xe5\xad\xa9\xe5\xad\x90\xe5\x90\x8e\xe5\x8f\x98\xe8\x80\x81'.decode('utf-8'))
27岁少妇生孩子后变老
```

Comment: That's why we need bytes() in the community. Any weird text can be like `\xe5\xb2\x81\xe5\xb0\x91\xe5\xa6\x87\xe7\x94\x9f\xe5\xad\xa9\xe5\xad\x90\xe5\x90\x8e\xe5\x8f\x98\xe8\x80\x81` :P

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Neither is better than the other, they do exactly the same thing. However, using `.encode()` and `.decode()` is the more common way to do it. It is also compatible with Python 2.

Comment: the only incompatibility with py2 is `.encode()` returns a bytes object instead of a str object (or unicode object in the OP's case).

Comment: Encode() returns an 8-bit string in both cases. It's called "str" in Python 2 and "bytes" in Python 3, but both are 8-bit strings.

Comment: str and bytes are 2 different classes, bytes is an 8bit array represented as a string, which is useful, but not co-converted between the two in this particular circumstance. (py2 was less of a headache here)

Comment: "str and bytes are 2 different classes" - In Python 3, yes. In Python 2, no.

I repeat: Encode() returns an 8-bit string both under Python 2 and Python 3. It's called "str" in Python 2 and "bytes" in Python 3, but both are 8-bit strings.

Comment: In fact, Python 3 is less of a headache than Python 2. One of the big reasons for Python 3 was that unicode was a big pain on Python 2.

Comment: agreed str vs unicode was just as much of a headache as int vs long, but str.decode in py2 was less of a headache to have to manage than bytes.decode in py3

Comment: They do the same thing, so I disagree.

Answer (score 19):

To add to [Lennart Regebro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473492/1346705) There is even the third way that can be used:

```
encoded3 = str.encode(original, 'utf-8')
print(encoded3)
```

Anyway, it is actually exactly the same as the first approach. It may also look that the second way is a syntactic sugar for the third approach.

---

A programming language is a means to express abstract ideas formally, to be executed by the machine. A programming language is considered good if it contains constructs that one needs. Python is a hybrid language -- i.e. more natural and more versatile than pure OO or pure procedural languages. Sometimes functions are more appropriate than the object methods, sometimes the reverse is true. It depends on mental picture of the solved problem.

Anyway, the feature mentioned in the question is probably a by-product of the language implementation/design. In my opinion, this is a nice example that show the alternative thinking about technically the same thing.

In other words, calling an object method means thinking in terms *"let the object gives me the wanted result"*. Calling a function as the alternative means *"let the outer code processes the passed argument and extracts the wanted value"*.

The first approach emphasizes the ability of the object to do the task on its own, the second approach emphasizes the ability of an separate algoritm to extract the data. Sometimes, the separate code may be that much special that it is not wise to add it as a general method to the class of the object.

Comment: Yes, actually now that I think of this it makes perfect sense.

Comment: it is the same as the first way: `'a'.encode('utf-8')` calls `str.encode('a', 'utf-8')`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes. I wrote it just below the code.

Answer (score 12):

To add to add to the previous answer, there is even a fourth way that can be used

```
import codecs
encoded4 = codecs.encode(original, 'utf-8')
print(encoded4)
```

Comment: note: unlike other variants, it works for arbitrary encodings e.g., for bytes -> bytes encodings: `codecs.encode(b'a','hex') -> b'61'`

Comment: I get that it can't convert bytes to string implicitly