# Python webpage source read with special characters

Tags: python, html, urlencode

I am reading a page source from a webpage, then parsing a value from that source.
There I am facing a problem with special characters.

In my python controller file iam using `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.
But I am reading a webpage source which is using `charset=iso-8859-1`

So when I read the page content without specifying any encoding it is throwing error as `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 133: invalid start byte`

when I use `string.decode("iso-8859-1").encode("utf-8")` then it is parsing data without any error. But it is displaying the value as 'F\u00fcnke' instead of 'Fünke'.

Please let me know how I can solve this issue.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: try print `u"F\u00fcnke"`

Comment: Python **2** or **3**?

Comment: Python 2.7. and tried unicode() it is showing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is a PITA in Python3 for sure (and 2 in some cases as well).
Try checking these links out, they might help you:

[Python - Encoding string - Swedish Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315629/python-encoding-string-swedish-letters)
[Python3 - ascii/utf-8/iso-8859-1 can't decode byte 0xe5 (Swedish characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260859/python3-ascii-utf-8-iso-8859-1-cant-decode-byte-0xe5-swedish-characters)

http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

Also it would be nice with the code for `"So when I read the page content without specifying any encoding"` My best guess is that your console doesn't use utf-8 (for instance, windows.. your `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` only tells Python what type of characters to find within the sourcecode, not the actual data the code is going to parse or analyze itself.
For instance i write:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import time
# Här skriver jag ut tiden (Translation: Here, i print out the time)
print(time.strftime('%H:%m:%s'))
```

Comment: And a downvote for no reason, real constructive (if i'm wrong at least point it out ffs) -.-