# Python send UDP packet

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to write a program to send UDP packets, as in  https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication The code appears to be in Python 2:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
             socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

If I put parenthesis around the printed stuff, it just prints it on the screen.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Are you running the example code to receive UDP packets? It won't appear to do anything (besides print to console) unless you've got something receiving the packets.

Comment: Do you see network traffic in wireshark?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

With Python3x, you need to convert your string to raw bytes. You would have to encode the string as bytes. Over the network you need to send bytes and not characters. You are right that this would work for Python 2x since in Python 2x, socket.sendto on a socket takes a "plain" string and not bytes. Try this:

```
print("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)
print("message:", MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8"), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked on wireshark, and it successfully sent a UDP packet. +1 Accepted answer.

Comment: this only works for messages that are text. Keep in mind you can transfer and receive arbitrary data over the network with these functions so you cannot always assume decode/encode as utf8 will make sense.

Comment: @user2957811 Ofc this works for messages that are not text? Just don't need to run it through `bytes`...

Answer (score 11):

**Your code works as is for me.** I'm verifying this by using [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) on Linux.

Using netcat, I can do `nc -ul 127.0.0.1 5005` which will listen for packets at:

- IP: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 5005
- Protocol: UDP

That being said, here's the output that I see when I run your script, while having netcat running.

```
[9:34am][wlynch@watermelon ~] nc -ul 127.0.0.1 5005
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 5):

Manoj answer above is correct, but another option is to use MESSAGE.encode() or encode('utf-8') to convert to bytes. bytes and encode are mostly the same, encode is compatible with python 2. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472650/python-3-encode-decode-vs-bytes-str) for more

full code:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

print("UDP target IP: %s" % UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port: %s" % UDP_PORT)
print("message: %s" % MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE.encode(), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running python 3 then you need to change the print statements to print functions, i.e. put things in brackets () after print statements.

The only thing that you will see the above do is the prints unless you have something listening on `127.0.0.1 port 5005` as you are **sending a packet** not *receiving* it - so you need to implement and start the other part of the example in another console window **first** so it is waiting for the message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example that has been tested with Python 2.7.5 on CentOS 7.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, socket

def main(args):
    ip = args[1]
    port = int(args[2])
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    file = 'sample.csv'

    fp = open(file, 'r')
    for line in fp:
        sock.sendto(line.encode('utf-8'), (ip, port))
    fp.close()

main(sys.argv)
```

The program reads a file, `sample.csv` from the current directory and sends each line in a separate UDP packet. If the program it were saved in a file named `send-udp` then one could run it by doing something like:

```
$ python send-udp 192.168.1.2 30088
```