# Why doesn't echo > /dev/udp/... work from subprocess.Popen() or os.system()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, subprocess

I'm writing a python (2.7) script where I have to execute some shell commands which will send UDP packets to a remote VM. To execute the command, I'm using the subprocess lib and using both Popen and call methods.

The following code shows my 2 approaches to send a UDP packet. The problem is, neither of them (call or Popen) work (nor does os.system, for the matter). The command is interpreted as a single echo of the string "hello > /dev/udp/192.168.85.36/3000", as shown when I print the output from the PIPE.

```
myCmd = 'echo hello > /dev/udp/192.168.85.36/3000'

subprocess.call(myCmd, shell=True)

subprocess.Popen(myCmd.split(), stderr=subprocess.PIPE,\ 
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'packet', '>','/dev/udp/192.168.85.36/3000'],\
                  shell=False, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The interesting thing is that when I execute the exact same command directly in a terminal, the UDP packet is received in the remote VM. The difference is that inside the program, the echo command is inside a loop, executing multiple times (which is the expected behaviour). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues that prevent this from working:

1. You are passing `>` and `/dev/udp/..` to `echo`. Handling `>` is not `echo`'s job. It's up to the shell. If you don't invoke a shell, it's *your* job.
2. `/dev/udp` is not a real device/directory. Bash intercepts it and opens a socket instead. If you don't run bash (and note that `shell=True` and `os.system` will instead run `sh`), opening a socket is *your* job.

The easiest way to fix it without taking on that extra work is to invoke `bash` to do it:

```
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'echo packet > /dev/udp/192.168.85.36/3000'], shell=False, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The best way to fix it is to use Python's UDP functionality, see e.g. [Python send UDP packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743962/python-send-udp-packet)

Comment: Maybe add something like "*(and `os.system()` and `shell=True` use `/bin/sh`, not bash)*" to the "if you don't run bash" statement?

Comment: More idiomatic would be to pass `executable="bash"`.