# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6723 Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, ascii, decode

```
text_file = open("university_towns.txt")
State = {idx: lines.decode('utf-8').strip().replace("[edit]", "") 
             for idx,lines in enumerate(text_file) if "edit" in lines}
```

My code raised an error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6723
```

I am using Python 3.5.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Looks like byte 6723 is not proper unicode. Passing `errors='ignore'` to ` decode()` might help.

Comment: In python 3.x, since you didn't specify an encoding the file was opened in whatever mode `sys.getdefaultencoding()` says. `lines.decode('utf-8')` is invalid because 3.x strings don't have a `decode` method so you didn't get that far or you'd have a different error. My guess is that the problem is in `enumerate(text_file)`... but that would mean your default encoding is `ascii`. You could just read the file line by line and see if you get the error just doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove decode("utf-8) from second line and it might solve your problem!

As in python 2 we make use of encode and decode for related problems. But in python 3.x , str/bytes make similar use of that.

You nay read the following reference:

[python-3-encode-decode-vs-bytes-str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472650/python-3-encode-decode-vs-bytes-str)

Hope, it helps!